# Better way to represent symmetric relationships in a relational db?

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, relationship, relation

```
Table User:
  Id = Integer, PrimaryKey

Table UserSimilarity:
  Id = Integer, PrimaryKey, Autoincrement
  User_a = ForeignKey(User.Id)
  User_b = ForeignKey(User.Id)
  Similarity = Float
```

Is there a better way than this to represent similarities between users?

Let's say I want to query the similarity between user 3 and user 5, then my query will go something like this:

`Select similarity where (user a = 3 and user b = 5) or (user a = 5 and user b = 3)`

Is there a way I can implement such design where I would not need to use "user_a" and "user_b"?

Comment: You're referring to things not in the code. What is "track_a"?

Comment: @DanMan sorry, I meant user_a and user_b

Comment: This is not clear. Please give a full design including what the tables mean & constraints & what query result you *do* want, ie via a query that returns it, & exactly what "better" means, & "similar", if you want an alternative. Please read & act on [mcve].